# How to get print event in windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am using PDF Exchange API for getting print events in windows console/form application. But when I write same code to make service, the code does not work with the service. I am using following code.

```
PXCComLib5.CPXCControlEx prnFactory = new PXCComLib5.CPXCControlEx();
PDFPrinter = (PXCComLib5.CPXCPrinter)prnFactory.get_Printer("", "Simple PDF-XChange 2012", "<REG CODE>", "<DEV CODE>");
PDFPrinter.Option["Save.ShowSaveDialog"] = false;
PDFPrinter.SetAsDefaultPrinter();

PDFPrinter.OnStartDoc += new PXCComLib5._IPXCPrinterEvents_OnStartDocEventHandler(prn_OnStartDoc);
PDFPrinter.OnFileSaved += new PXCComLib5._IPXCPrinterEvents_OnFileSavedEventHandler(prn_OnFileSaved);
PDFPrinter.OnDocSpooled += new PXCComLib5._IPXCPrinterEvents_OnDocSpooledEventHandler(prn_OnDocSpooled);
PDFPrinter.OnError += new PXCComLib5._IPXCPrinterEvents_OnErrorEventHandler(prn_OnError);
PDFPrinter.OnStartPage += new PXCComLib5._IPXCPrinterEvents_OnStartPageEventHandler(prn_OnStartPage);
PDFPrinter.OnEndPage += new PXCComLib5._IPXCPrinterEvents_OnEndPageEventHandler(prn_OnEndPage);
PDFPrinter.OnEndDoc += new PXCComLib5._IPXCPrinterEvents_OnEndDocEventHandler(prn_OnEndDoc);
```

The methods are like:

```
void prn_OnStartPage(int JobID, int nPageNumber)
{
     logger.Trace("StartPageEvent called");
}
```

same way other methods are defined.

This code works when used as windows console/Form application but not working with windows service.
Also I have tried the option **Enable Desktop Interaction** after installing the service.
I am using Windows 7 and visual studio 2010. 
Is there any extra configuration I need to do?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Shooting: did you try to use another principal for windows service - other then Local System? Try to set your own user as principal for windows service.

Comment: @huhu78 I tried that also but it did not worked.

Comment: And are you sure about your logger while it's working under windows service? Maybe it's not a case related to those events?!

Comment: @huhu78 logger is defined by me, I am not using any library for that. It is simple appending into a file with date-time.